Extract content attribute from xml with same tag and name
I am getting an xml from an api and I want to be able to map it directly into a pojo, but the structure of the xml is as follows:
 <xml>
      <meta-info>
        <meta name="id" content="1234-5678"/>
        <meta name="title" content="test"/>
        <meta name="fileType" content="txt"/>
        <meta name="priority" content="low"/>
      </meta-info>
    </xml>

And I want to be able to map it to an object that has
String Id;
String title;
String fileType;
String priority;

I have tried using the XmlPath annotations:
@XmlRootElement(name="xml")
@XmlType(propOrder={"id", "title", "fileType", "priority"})
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class XmlMapTest {

    @XmlPath("xml[@name='id']")
    private String id;
    
    @XmlPath("xml[@name='title']")
    private String title;
    
    @XmlPath("xml[@name='fileType']")
    private String fileType;
    
    @XmlPath("xml[@name='priority']")
    private String priority;
   

}

But I always get the same error:
"com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "meta-info" (class hibernateTests.XmlMapTest), not marked as ignorable (0 known properties: ])"

In all the other examples that I have seen, the example only takes the info from the name attribute, not from the content.
Is there away to do this directly?
Edit:
I switched from using Javax XmlMapper as:
XmlMapTest xmlResult = mapper.readValue(xml, XmlMapTest.class);

To using:
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(XmlMapTest.class);
       XmlMapTest xmlResult= (XmlMapTest) jc.createUnmarshaller().unmarshal(new StringReader(xml));

And although I dont get the error anymore, all the results come out as null:
----------------------------------------------------------------
Id:             null
Title:          null
FileType:       null
Priority:       null
----------------------------------------------------------------


Do you rely on FasterXML or are other libraries also an option? Does your xml always contain one meta-info element or can there be several?

Your XPath expressions are slightly off.
Please try the following adjustments.
Java
@XmlRootElement(name="xml")
@XmlType(propOrder={"id", "title", "fileType", "priority"})
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class XmlMapTest {

    @XmlPath("meta-info/meta[@name='id']/@content")
    private String id;
    
    @XmlPath("meta-info/meta[@name='title']/@content")
    private String title;
    
    @XmlPath("meta-info/meta[@name='fileType']/@content")
    private String fileType;
    
    @XmlPath("meta-info/meta[@name='priority']/@content")
    private String priority;
}

Java #2
import jakarta.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import jakarta.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import jakarta.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

import static java.lang.StringTemplate.STR;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.Serializable;
import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.annotations.XmlPath;

public class Jakarta_XmlToObject {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = null;
        try {
            File file = new File(
                    "c:\\Users\\...\\input.xml");

            // Normal JAXB RI
            // jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Settings.class);

            // we need this way to perform XPath based mapping via @XmlPath !!!
            jaxbContext = org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory
                    .createContext(new Class[] { Settings.class }, null);
            Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
            Settings o = (Settings) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);

            System.out.println(o);
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @XmlRootElement(name="xml")
    @XmlType(propOrder={"id", "title", "fileType", "priority"})
    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    public class XmlMapTest {

    @XmlPath("meta-info/meta[@name='id']/@content")
    private String id;

    @XmlPath("meta-info/meta[@name='title']/@content")
    private String title;

    @XmlPath("meta-info/meta[@name='fileType']/@content")
    private String fileType;

    @XmlPath("meta-info/meta[@name='priority']/@content")
    private String priority;

    }
}


Thanks for the quick response, I made the change suggested, but I still get the same error mentioned above.

I adjusted the answer. Please try it now.

I also tried these changes before, but the error persist with the exact same message.

I added Java #2, full implementation

Hi, Im testing this and wanted to know what exactly is in the Settings.class?

 "java.project.referencedLibraries": [         "lib/**/*.jar",         "e:\\Kit\\Jakarta\\jaxb-ri\\mod\\angus-activation.jar",         "e:\\Kit\\Jakarta\\jaxb-ri\\mod\\jakarta.activation-api.jar",         "e:\\Kit\\Jakarta\\jaxb-ri\\mod\\jakarta.xml.bind-api.jar",         "e:\\Kit\\Jakarta\\jaxb-ri\\mod\\jaxb-core.jar",         "e:\\Kit\\Jakarta\\jaxb-ri\\mod\\jaxb-impl.jar",         "e:\\Kit\\Jakarta\\jaxb-ri\\mod\\jaxb-jxc.jar",         "e:\\Kit\\Jakarta\\jaxb-ri\\mod\\jaxb-xjc.jar",         "e:\\Kit\\EclipseLink\\eclipselink-4.0.2.jar"     ]
